# What does tx.gasprice represent after EIP-1559?

Tags: solidity, gas-price

Now that ethereum has switched to using a base and priority fee system, what does `tx.gasprice` represent in solidity? Would calculating `tx.gasprice - block.basefee` give me the priority fee for the transaction?

Comment: Were you able to find the answer for this @jonah?

Comment: yes. `tx.gasprice - block.basefee` does equal the priority fee per gas. At least that's what I concluded from sending test transactions to my solidity contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified by the EIP:

> The GASPRICE (0x3a) opcode MUST return the effective_gas_price

```
priority_fee_per_gas = min(transaction.max_priority_fee_per_gas, transaction.max_fee_per_gas - block.base_fee_per_gas)
effective_gas_price = priority_fee_per_gas + block.base_fee_per_gas
```

So `tx.gasprice` returns the actual gas price of the transaction (even post -1559)